# Regex for Comma Separated Number or Just Number

Tags: c#, regex, .net-3.5

This is something of a follow up from [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359147/regex-for-comma-separated-number). The requirements have changed, and I'm looking for some help with coming up with regex for either a comma separated number or a number with no commas. Sample input is below, along with some failed attempts.

Any help is appreciated.

Acceptable input:

```
1,234,567
1234567
```

Unacceptable input:

```
1234,567
1,234567
```

Some failed attempts:

```
^(\d{1,3}(?:[,]\d{3})*)|((\d)*)$
^\d{1,3}((?:[,]?\d{3})*|(?:[,]\d{3})*)$
```

Original success:

```
^\d{1,3}(?:[,]\d{3})*$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an "or one or more digits" to the end:

```
^(?:\d{1,3}(?:[,]\d{3})*|\d+)$
```

I think you had it almost right the first time and just didn't match up all your parentheses correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^\d{1,3}(?:(?:,\d{3})+|\d*)$
```

This will match any sequence that begins with one to three digits, followed by either

- one or more segments of a comma followed by three digits, or
- zero or more digits.

Comment: +1 for correctly dealing with the right number of comma groups. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246077/simple-problem-with-regular-expression-only-digits-and-commas/4247184#4247184) for a broader discussion and elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)() rathern then a regex?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246077/simple-problem-with-regular-expression-only-digits-and-commas/4247184#4247184) for a definitive treatment of the “Is it a number?” question, including allowance for *correctly* comma-separated digit groups.

Answer (score 0):

One thing i've noticed with all these is that the first bit of the regex allows for '0' based numbers to work. For example the number:

```
0,123,456
```

Would match using the accepted answer. I've been using:

```
((?<!\w)[+-]?[1-9][0-9]{,2}(?:,[0-9]{3})+)
```

Which also ensures that the number has nothing in front of it. It does *not* catch numbers of less then 1,000 however. This was to prevent ill-formatted numbers from being captured at all. If the final `+` were a `?` the following numbers would be captured:

```
0,123
1,2 (as 2 separate numbers)
```

I have a strange set of numbers to match for (integers with commas, with spaces and without both), so i'm using pretty restrictive regexs to capture these groups.

Anyway, something to think about!