# Regex for optional comma separated number with decimal point

Tags: regex

I'm after a regular expression which will match the following

```
1,245.30
24,235,235.50
12235235.60
235.50
```

The decimal is mandatory but I'd like the comma to be optional. Based off this answer [Regex for Comma Separated Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359147/regex-for-comma-separated-number) I was able to come up with this expression which works great for the comma separated numbers.

```
(^\d{1,3}([,]\d{3})*([.]\d{2}){0,1}$)
```

However I'm having trouble making the commas optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, just allow a number without commas as an explicit alternative:

```
^(\d?\d?\d(,\d\d\d)*|\d+)(\.\d\d)?$
```