# How to Apply Regex Validation to a textbox in JQuery to enter only decimal(s),integer(s) numbers(if multiple comma seperated)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

My HTML Code is

```
<input type="text" class="form-control textinput" id="Result" name="Result" value="@p.Result"/>
```

My JQuery Code is :

```
$(function () {

    $(".textinput").keydown(function (e) {
        var test = ^(\d?\d?\d(,\d\d\d)*|\d+)(\.\d\d)?$;
        var value = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        if (value.match(test)) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

I have reffered to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199085/regex-for-optional-comma-separated-number-with-decimal-point) but it isn't working,showing an error so please help

My Sample Inputs will be as follows

> 1,245.30
>
> 24,235
>
> 135.60,12.6
>
> 235.50
>
> 34

Comment: is this valid ? `1,2,3,4,5`

Comment: yes its a valid input

Comment: Your can't use this regex and keydown. Console log value, and see - you are checking characters, one by one, hence, there will be no match. Also, regex should be inside quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one: `^\d+((?=[\,\.])([\.\,]\d+|$))*$`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex

```
^(?:\d+,)*\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/GYvpB0/1)

Comment: Please help me with the JS code its still showing me error