# Comma separated numbers regex - accepts pipe character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written a small regex for javascript. It should only accept numbers separated by commas.

Valid examples are:

```
1 single value allowed
1,278,3780,50
1,56,90, (trailing comma allowed)
```

Invalid examples are:

1,45  67

```
1, gj, + (any special character and characters)
```

The regex is: `/^[\d|\,]+/g`

However, it also accepts | (pipe character).

```
Like: 1|46|6778|567
```

What am I doing wrong? What did I miss?
Please follow this [link](https://regex101.com/r/sY3lI6/1) to my regex

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for Comma Separated Number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359147/regex-for-comma-separated-number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need pipe (`|`) and escaping characters within character class. Also as a proper way you can use following regex:

```
 /^(?:\d+\,)+\d+$/g
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/4xZ2zGbXocQxIORH)

As i missed your edit if the trailing comma is a valid case you can simply use following regex :

```
^(\d+,?)+$
```

Comment: What about last comma

Comment: your regex also allows this input 57,,,,,,578678,678,67,678,678,,,,,6,78,6
My requirement involves only one comma per separation

Comment: I ended up writing this regex
`^(?:\d+\,)*\d+\,{0,1}$`
I still don't know what `?:` this is...I know its called a capturing group but what it does and when to use it know idea!

Comment: Go with @Andie2302's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30621011/4044587). This does not match your requirement to match a single value and should not be marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: @ShekharJoshi Its none capture grouping and makes you regex engine doesn't return the matched pattern by that group

Comment: @md4 That answer is incorrect because it match comma in end of string!!! and about my answer yes it doesn't match single number but OP wants numbers separated with comma!!!!

Comment: The OP says that a trailing comma is a *valid* example. Also, go easy on the exclamation marks. It looks like you're yelling.

Comment: @kasramvd I know its an old question. But for learning,  Can you explain what you meant by the first sentence in your answer?

Comment: @KiraAG Character class is for matching a combination of characters which makes use of logical or obsolete. Plus there's no need to escape regex characters too like `[\*]` is the same as `[*]`. The character class escape those characters automatically. The only exception is close bracket which should be escaped to not be mistaken with the character class's closing bracket.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
^\d+\,(?:\d+\,?)+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zO6qQ9/2)

**EDIT:**
With changed requirements -

```
^\d+(?:,\d+)*,?$
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/zO6qQ9/5)

Comment: This fails to match single values (with or without trailing commas).

Comment: @md4 Yep, The question was edited after I wrote the answer. `Single value not allowed` was added after I answered. Will add that for completeness. Thanks :)

Comment: I realised that after I said the same thing to @Kasra. I really do need to pay attention to question edits in future.

Answer (score 1):

To match a number separated by comma:

```
(\d+,?)+
```

Comment: Upvoted for the sheer simplicity. For completeness sake, it should be anchored to avoid matching invalid strings that merely contain the delimited number sequence.

Comment: @Kasra, as stated above, that is a *valid* example as per the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The correct regex is as follows:

```
^\d+(?:,\d+)*,?$
```

This will match the cases specified:

- A single number (`1`)
- A series of numbers delimited by commas (`1,2,3`)
- An optional trailing comma (`1,`, `1,2,3,4,`)